# How can i skip records with same values that follow each other?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which stores bunch of records like this:

```
Time  UserName  
10:30   John   
10:40   John  
10:45   John  
11:05   Sara  
11:07   John   
11:08   Ned  
11:09   Ned
```

But I need to somehow skip records with same `UserName` as in previous record, so only record with first `UserName` will be in result, like so:

```
Time  UserName  
10:30   John   
11:05   Sara  
11:07   John   
11:08   Ned
```

It's very obvious how to do this in regular programming languages, but I can't understand how to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest method is to use `lag()`:

```
select t.time, t.name
from (select t.*,
             lag(name) over (order by time) as prev_name
      from t
     ) t
where prev_name is null or prev_name <> name;
```

I would imagine that this also has the best performance.

Comment: I agree regarding performance; it is at least the best-performing of the posted answers (including mine - Gordon's solution has only half the cost compared to my solution, comparing the execution plans). +1

Answer (score 3):

The query below uses the "gaps and islands" method (a.k.a. "tabibitosan" method) to group together CONSECUTIVE rows with the same `username`.

This only works if all times are distinct (otherwise the output from `row_number()` is not deterministic); but if the times are not all distinct, there is no "natural" sense of "consecutive" names anyway (in that case the problem itself needs to be clarified).

```
select min(time) as time, username from
    (select time, username,
            row_number() over (order by time) -
                   row_number() over (partition by username order by time) as gp
     from   inputs
    )
group by username, gp
order by time;
```

`inputs` is the base table.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
select t1.Time  ,t1.UserName from 
   ( select Time  ,UserName
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  ORDER BY Time,UserName ) R from table) t1
    join ( select Time  ,UserName
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  ORDER BY Time,UserName ) R from table) t2
    on t1.R = t2.R - 1
    where t1.UserName <> t2.UserName;
```

Comment: This solution will only return the first row for each `username`. This was not the requirement; with the OP's test data, this query will miss the second occurrence of John, at 11:07 (which is not consecutive to the other "John" rows).

Answer (score 1):

This will work in all DBs without even analytic functions:

```
select * from temp t1 
where not exists ( select 1 from temp t2 
       where t2.UserName = t1.UserName
         and t2.Time < t1.Time 
         and not exists (select 1 from temp t3 
                where t3.UserName != t2.UserName 
                and t3.Time > t2.Time 
                and t3.Time < t1.Time 
                        ) 
                 ) ;
```

The inner query ensures there is no other same name that appears before another name in between.